# Keyboard events: Is the order guaranteed?

Tags: c#, java, c++, winapi, keyboard

For pressing a single key, there are multiple events that can be handled.

There is: `KeyDown`, `KeyPressed`, `KeyUp`.

Is it guaranteed that an application will receive those events in that order?

What I mean is: is the order of a single key pressing event, not a series of different keys pressed.

**Context:**

After I had some problems with keypress-events in a legacy C++ application
I inspected the events with `spy++`. There I saw that the order seems sometimes
not to be right and the `keypressed` is not fired for every `keydown`or `keyup`.

But, I was sure that the events should be fired in exactly that order, but
could not find anything on the internet. So I came up with this question here.

Please note that this is not a multiple languages problem, but I am interested whether this is true for C++, Java and C#.

Comment: I would assume yes? Otherwise this comment would become: "I dulwo musame sey. wshteirO shti meomcnt lduow cebmeo."

Comment: I want to know if it is garanteed for a single key pressed, not for a series of key ups, key downs etc. they are garanteed to be sequential.

Comment: Is your current application written in C#, Java, and C++ combined? All I can say is, "wow"! I'm glad that I don't have to maintain it!

Comment: The problem arises in a C++ application, but I am interested in Java and C# also. Maybe this is language specific. Why not maintaining it? This is legacy code, and I am just curious if the order is guaranteed or not

Comment: I think `KeyPressed` is only fired if a character is produced. i.e. deadkeys and modifier keys (and probably some IME related stuff as well) won't trigger it.

Comment: It's likely platform specific more so than language specific.

Comment: Speaking for Java, I have never seen the events arrive out of order, and that would not make any sense to begin with. I am not aware of a formal guarantee though.

Comment: And that is why I asked here, as I do not find any information on google on that

Comment: I think it's fair enough to tag this with three different language tags to attract relevant eyes from each languages experts. Although it would be useful if you were specific about which language you're seeing the problem being exhibited.

Comment: @Kev: I have edited in more context, on how I came up with that question and what I have tried.

Comment: Why is it important for you to rely on the order? The order itself is such a minute detail, but whatever you're trying to accomplish likely needs to make far more assumptions, which scares me.

Comment: I do not try to accomplish anything but knowing whether this is true or not. I assummed it as long as I am a software developer, but now I am in doubt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They should happen in that order when they happen, in most apps.  But your window might not receive every event for every character entered.

For example, in Windows, if you hold down a key you'll see a `KeyDown` and/or `KeyPressed` repeatedly as the key repeats, and a single `KeyUp` once the key is released.

### Edit:

Now that i think about it, though...Windows starts out only posting `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_KEYUP` messages to your window (and only if you have focus).  `WM_CHAR` messages (the Win32 analogue to `KeyPressed`) are posted based on those when the message loop calls `TranslateMessage`.  This means two things:

- If the window has a backlog of messages, the API *might* just add the message to the end of the queue (IDK); this makes more sense to me (the message queue being a *queue*, after all, and not a stack), but it does mean that if there is already a `WM_KEYUP` for that key in the queue (for example, if the user hit and released a key while another message was being processed), the corresponding `WM_CHAR` might appear *after* it.
- Languages like C and C++ have more flexibility (read: less built-in automation) in how they handle messages; in order for them to get `WM_CHAR` messages, they have to either call `TranslateMessage` explicitly or do the translation themselves (barring another app posting such messages to it).  With the latter, there's no telling what order the messages will be posted in.

Also, as mentioned in the comments, if the focus switches while a key is down, you might only see a `KeyUp` or `KeyDown`.  (The key state was already that way before the focus switch, and Windows probably won't tell you about it.)  And dead keys (ones that don't generate a character on their own) won't trigger a `KeyPressed` at all (though they do typically trigger `KeyUp` and `KeyDown`).  They typically just wait for the next real character and modify it.

**Short version of all that**:  You can rely on the order in which `KeyDown` events appear in relation to each other.  Same with `KeyPressed`, and even `KeyUp`.  But, at least in Windows, the three message types are not really coordinated with each other.  So don't assume that every `KeyUp` will match a `KeyDown` (or vice versa), or that `KeyPressed` appears before `KeyUp`.

You should probably also decide whether you want to process *characters* or *keys*.  That's part of the confusion here, i think; the two are actually different concepts, and most of the time you only really care about one or the other.  While Win32 would allegedly tell you the key code when you're handling a `KeyPressed` event, the real intent of that event is to tell you what *character* was entered.  (There's a reason it's called `WM_CHAR` and not `WM_KEYPRESS`.  :)  And why .net's `KeyPressEventArgs` type only has a `KeyChar` and not a `KeyCode`.)  The other two treat the keyboard as basically a bunch of buttons.

Comment: That, plus consider dead keys.

Comment: Also consider app 1 receiving WM_KEYDOWN, and app 2 receiving the corresponding WM_KEYUP. The order is guaranteed, but it's still important to make as few assumptions about these messages as possible. Keyboard input is extremely sensitive and if it starts feeling like a hack, do NOT continue doing it

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer! Thats exactly what I thought, i.e. that no assumptions can be made! I do not make any assumptions. I personally like to listen to WM_KEYDOWN and not WM_CHAR, but this is legacy code and I won't fix anything that aint broke.

Answer (score 0):

If you are Windows user, the rule of thumb here is: check the order of events by logging or in debugger and then assume that this will be always so.

This is not perfect, but this works in 95% of cases. I many times heard stories that Windows team always pushes back to change anything because 100% sure this will break something.

This is direct result of poor documentation of the Windows 2.0 era.

Comment: It is probably in 99.99% in that order, but can I rely on that?

Comment: How can you rely on anything that is not **explicitly** expressed in the **official** docs?

Comment: That is exactly the question. Can I rely on it? Is it stated somewhere in the official docs? Perhaps winapi comes in here.

Comment: I never saw anything like that in the MS docs. I can bet it is not there.